# Top aligning ImageView and TextView in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a company logo image at the top of the display and immediately underneath this I want a `TextView` to display the current user.  However it must display on different width displays which are always mobile phones.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageLogo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:contentDescription="@string/lets_delight_logo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Not logged on..."
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageLogo" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

If I set the `layout_height` of the `ImageView` to a fixed value then I can get it to work right on one display width but not a different width.  If I set the `layout_height` to `wrap_content` then the image is vertically centered instead of being at the top of the display despite setting `layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` unless I set `scaleType="fitStart"` which moves the image to the top of the display.

However, with `scaleType="fitStart"` the `TextView` is displayed vertically centered in the space between the bottom of the `ImageView` and the bottom of the screen.  Not immediately below the `ImageView` despite setting `layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageLogo"`

How can I get the `ImageView` to automatically scale to the height of the image when displayed at full screen width and in a way that allows the `TextView` to locate immediately underneath?

Comment: You want to do this using RelativeLayout or ConstraintLayout? As in your code you have used ConstraintLayout and your question mentions RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem...
The `ImageView` was being displayed as a square image with both the height and width being set to the width of the display and the `TextView` under the square.

Adding this to the `ImageView` displays the image in its native aspect ratio and everything displays as expected :)

> android:adjustViewBounds="true"